# Add style color red to an appended li but every 3rd time only- Javascript

Tags: javascript

it should be like

```
<ul id="list">
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li> <- Text should be red
...
<li>6</li> <- red
</ul>
```

I want such that when i click on the button tag, the content value  of the input tag is added as li tag but for every 3rd time i added the text needs to be red how to do this in JavaScript,

```
   <div>
      <input id="text" type="text" />
      <button id="add">Add</button>
    </div>

    <ul id="list"></ul>
```

```
      (function () {
        document.querySelector('#add').addEventListener('click', function () {
          let input = document.querySelector('#text');
          if (input.value !== '') {
            let list = document.querySelector('#list');

            let item = document.createElement('li'); // create li node
            let itemText = document.createTextNode(input.value); // create text node

            item.appendChild(itemText); // append text node to li nod
            list.appendChild(item); // append li node to list

            input.value = ''; // clear input
          } else {
            alert('Input text value');
          }
        });
      })();
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, you want the added li to be in red color for 3 seconds.

If so, you can add a style for the new li and remove it in setTimeout of 3 seconds:

```
item.classList.add("new-added-item");
setTimeout(() => {
    item.classList.remove("new-added-item");
}, 3000);
```

```js
(function () {
        document.querySelector('#add').addEventListener('click', function () {
          let input = document.querySelector('#text');
          if (input.value !== '') {
            let list = document.querySelector('#list');

            let item = document.createElement('li'); // create li node
            let itemText = document.createTextNode(input.value); // create text node

            item.appendChild(itemText); // append text node to li nod
            list.appendChild(item); // append li node to list
           
            input.value = ''; // clear input
            
            item.classList.add("new-added-item");
            setTimeout(() => {
              item.classList.remove("new-added-item");
            }, 3000);
          } else {
            alert('Input text value');
          }
        });
      })();
```

```css
.new-added-item {
   color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
      <input id="text" type="text" />
      <button id="add">Add</button>
    </div>

    <ul id="list"></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can choose the 3rd and 6th `<li>` to be colored in red with the following CSS code :

```js
li:nth-of-type(3) {
color: red;
}

li:nth-of-type(6) {
color: red;
}
```